# Racket: is it possible to set surface3d steps differently for two axes?

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a 3D plot with racket's plot library.
Ho do I make surface3d evaluate my function only in certain points? I mean, I have an function defined only on integers, but surface3d tries to evaluate it somewhere in between them, seemingly according to samples parameter. Is it possible to set that parameter differently for two axes, so that the function would be evaluated only where it is defined, or should I better use some other function for plotting?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that surface3d evaluates the function in non-integer points, then 
you can define a function that uses the values of the nearby integer points to 
calculate an value for points inside the square.

If your functions is called f, then an first attempt is:

```
 (define (g x y)
    (f (floor x) (floor y)))
```

That will give you "stairs".

If you want a smoother appoach you can look at bilinear interpolation.
    [Bilinear Interpolation - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)

Comment: Actually, interpolation is what I expect from the plotter:) And re-calculating the function in the same points turns out to have a big performance drawback.

Comment: A new idea: Make sure xmax-xmin = ymax-ymin and that it is an integer. Then set #:samples to xmax-xmin. If you are lucky it will sample in integer points, if not you can use the floor trick.

Comment: The problem is that the function is defined on a rectangle, not a square. If xmax-xmin was equal to ymax-ymin, I'd set samples as you said and got what I want (that actually works for 2d plots)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you need to send Neil a feature request :-)

Comment: Well, I need to do this in two days, guess I won't get it filled in time :) Anyway, thanks for your ideas.